# Where do the responsibilities of memory management lie in a web application?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, memory, browser, memory-leaks

I'm trying to debug an array of issues with a client that seem to be facing memory leak issues with our web application. After recording a macro script that simply navigates our web application repeatedly, we found that all major browsers consumed more and more memory over time, which would cause many out of memory issues for flash and javascript etc. Internet explorer was the biggest culprit requiring a memory commit of nearly 1.5 gb within 25 minutes. Our web app heavily uses flash, which from my research is also a big memory leak cuprit. Having said all this, my question is what is primarily responsible for memory management? I know the browser is responsible for releasing and taking up memory on the process level, but if we are observing a memory leak with continual usage what should we be focusing on to address the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you need to clarify. If the problem seems to be related to Flash, do you reload the entire page containing Flash applets or do you use it continuously?

If you reload it - the problem may be on the JavaScript side, where some JavaScript references to Flash objects persist over sessions of viewing a single page (this is rare but not impossible, at some point Skype was known to cause such problems with their overlays for callable phone-numbers which messed something in the ExternalInterface wrapper and caused not only themselves, but every page containing Flash to remain in browser's memory forever).

Flash applet, if you don't reload it, should be managing its own memory itself, neither the browser, nor the plugin wrapper, not even the player are responsible for it. However, Flash uses similar to Java memory management model, which means, it cannot technically allocate memory which will not be reclaimed after the application is shut down, which means that if you make sure Flash applet is reloaded, then even if the applet itself is leaking, after it is unloaded, all the memory it used should be reclaimed.

Generally, AS3 uses more advanced programming, and there is more of it, compared to JavaScript, so, I would start searching for the problems there (as there's a bigger potential to make a mistake in a more complex code). Flash has several memory profilers available. There's one in Flash Builder, FlashDevelop has one too, there's also one known not bound to any IDE: http://jpauclair.net/2012/07/11/new-tutorial-profiling-memory-with-theminer/
There's also a project known as Monocle (used to be Telemetry), I'm not sure it was released yet, but it was demonstrated by Adobe on the last MAX event, here's one of the Adobe engineers talking about it: https://adobechats.adobeconnect.com/_a200985228/p4khwz03sz9/?launcher=false&fcsContent=true&pbMode=normal (more towards the middle of the presentation).

As for the JavaScript, here's something I came across some time ago: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance%3aLeak_Tools the recommendations from Mozilla. However, I also remember needing to build Mozilla browser from sources in order to enable memory profiling (you'd need to set some variable related to profiler output if you do that). Here's similar info on Chrome: http://zetafleet.com/blog/google-chromes-heap-profiler-and-memory-timeline . Perhaps, there are some tools in Visual Studio to profile JavaScript in IE - that I do not know.